# can someone explain how ajax works (conceptually not code)?

Tags: ajax

I've been using ajax for years now, but really never understood how it works in the background.

is the XMLHTTPRequest just a normal HTTPRequest with a different format?
how many simultaneous XMLHTTPRequests can the server handle?
exactly, whats the asynchronous part of the request?

So may questions...

Can you explain or point a good resource to read?

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous part means that you can make a request to server and receive data without the whole web page reloading.

How many requests depends on your server.